# numpy dot product with inner dimension zero gives unexpected result

Tags: numpy

My calculation consists of putting many matrices in one big block matrix. Some of these matrices can be empty in certain cases. These empty matrices give unexpected results.

The problem comes down to this:

```
b
Out[117]: array([], dtype=int32)

X = A[b,:]
Out[118]: array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)
```

`X` is the empty matrix. The matrix it gets multiplied by is also empty due to the code.

```
Y = array([]).dot(X)
Out[119]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
```

I realise that the size of `Y` is correct according to algebra: (1x0).(0x3)=(1x3). But I was expecting an empty matrix to be the result, since the inner dimmension of the matrices are zero (not one),

I would rather not check for these matrices to be empty, because putting the block matrix together, would have to be rewriten for every combination of the possible empty matrices.

Is there a solution to this problem? I was thinking of wrapping the dot function and only proceding if the inner dimension is not zero. But I feel like there is a cleaner solution.

edit:
I should clarify i bit more with what I mean with that I rather not check for zero dimension. The equations that i put into a block matrix consists of a hundreths of these dot products. Each dot product represents a component in an electrical network. X being empty means that there is no such component present in the network. But if I would have to compose the final (block) matrix dependent on which elements are presents. Then this would mean thousands of lines of code. Because the [ 0., 0., 0.] equation adds an incorrect equation. Which I would rather not do.

Comment: (1x0).(0x3)->[[0, 0, 0]] is correct behavior because the resulting shape is independent of the inner dimension, and 0 is the additive identity. Can you elaborate more on why this is causing problems for you?

Comment: `X.size == 0` => You don't need to check all the possible combinations. That is the easy way to check if any matrix is empty.

Comment: @JeroenBlofs. I made an update. Let me know if that helps any. It would really help to see a bit more than just the abstract of code you provided if you want some real help with your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad news is that the shape of the result is both expected and correct.

The good news is that there is a nearly trivial check to see if a matrix is empty or not for *all* cases using the total number of elements in the result, provided by the `size` attribute:

```
b = ...
X = ...
Y = array([]).dot(X)
if Y.size:
    # You have a non-empty result
```

**EDIT**

You can use the same logic to filter your input vectors. Since you want to do calculations only for non-empty vectors, you may want to try something like:

```
if b.size and X.size:
    Y = b.dot(X)
    # Add Y to your block matrix, knowing that it is of the expected size
```

Comment: I should clarify I bit more with what I mean with that I rather not check for zero dimension. The equations that I put into a block matrix consists of a hundreths of these dot products. Each dot product represents a component in an electrical network. `X` being empty means that there is no such component present in the network. But if i would have to compose the final (block) matrix dependent on which elements are presents. Then this would mean thousands of lines of code. Because the [ 0.,  0.,  0.] equation adds an incorrect equation. Which I would rather not do.

Comment: To add more on that. Matlab has correct behaviour, because an empty array `array([])` gets seen as size `0x0`which would result in an empty array by following the rules of dot products.

Comment: `y=np.zeros((0,0))` should work as in MATLAB.  If you want to emulate MATLAB make sure the 2d dimensions of your arrays are consistent.  In Octave `zeros(1,0)*x` produces a (1,3) matrix.